# How to change library search patch for GCC built with Yocto?

Tags: gcc, sdk, yocto

With Yocto (3.1 Dunfell) I try to build SDK containing both target (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-) and nativesdk (x86_64-sdk-linux-) GCC toolchains (GCC 9.1).

For the latter I modified libs default installation path:

`libdir_class-nativesdk = "${exec_prefix}/lib/${TARGET_SYS}"`

It gets installed in the proper locations now, but it also changed compilers default library search path:

`$ x86_64-sdk-linux-gcc -print-search-dirs | tr ':' '\n' /home/mfr/Devel/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-sdk-linux/lib/ /home/mfr/Devel/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-sdk-linux/usr/lib/x86_64-sdk-linux/`

**/home/mfr/Devel/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-sdk-linux/usr/lib** is missing now.
How can I add that path to the default libs search list?